# Append child on HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the follow code where I am trying to add a compiled HTML string inside multiple tags, but the elements are not beeing inserted:

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    var ctxmenu = $compile('<a context-menu="menuOptions">click here</a>')($scope);
    document.getElementById("box-"+i).append(ctxmenu[0]);
}
```

If i try to add it without `for loop` like that:

```
document.getElementById("box-"+i).append(ctxmenu[0]);
```

Then it will work.
Any ideias how to do that?

---

**EDIT**

The problem was that I was using `.append()` method instead of `.appendChild()`.

Comment: What is boxes? Please add other important parts of your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually" ?

Comment: You're mixing JS & jQuery in a weird way

Comment: That's actually not jQuery.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I am using `angularJS` too

Comment: It's `.appendChild();`.

Comment: Just because something has a dollar sign in it, doesn't make it jQuery...

Comment: @AluanHaddad `append()` belong to Angular ?

Comment: It's a DOM API actually.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez that was the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), it's [**`.appendChild(NodeElement)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

> The `Node.appendChild()` method adds a node to the end of the list of
>   children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference
>   to an existing node in the document, `appendChild()` moves it from its
>   current position to the new position (there is no requirement to
>   remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other
>   node).

Change:

```
document.getElementById("box-"+i).append(ctxmenu[0]);
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("box-"+i).appendChild(ctxmenu[0]);
```

The [**`.append()`**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method belongs to [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).